# Formatting date without time for jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datetime, datatables

I am trying to display a date, coming from SQL database, in date-only format with no time info and not lose sorting functionality.

I tried different ways and still can't get the darn thing to work.

1. I tried to convert in SQL query to date and no time:

   ```
   select ..., CAST(t.StartDate AS DATE) StartDate, ...
   ```
2. I tried a javascript function to convert to date string; works fine for displaying but in datatabe sorts like string and not date:

   ```
   function stringToDatestamp(dateString) {
       var date = new Date(dateString);

       var yr = date.getFullYear();
       var mo = date.getMonth() + 1;
       var d = date.getDate();
       var month = mo < 10 ? '0' + mo : mo;
       var day = d < 10 ? '0' + d : d;
       var newDateString = month + '/' + day + "/" + yr;
       return newDateString;
   }

   "columnDefs": [
       ....
       {
           "targets": [6],
           "render": function (data, type, row) {
               if (null == data)
                   return data;
               return stringToDatestamp(data);
           }
       }
   ],
   ```
3. Tried "moment.js" formatter:

   ```
   function stringToDatestamp(dateString) {debugger
       var date = moment(dateString).format("MM/dd/yyyy");
       return date;
   }

   // This display 2018-10-26T00:00:00 as 10/Fr/yyyy
   ```

Without any formatting, data is displated as 2018-10-26T00:00:00, even though in SQL query I used CAST.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but you may want to consider `toLocaleDateString()`

This is more succinct than your stringToDatestamp function.

Example:

```js
var date = new Date();
var today = date.toLocaleDateString();
console.log('today is:', today)
```

For your table, perhaps you could keep the value of each cell as the original data object for sorting purposes, and then display the result of the toLocaleDateString() in the html.

Comment: but it seems what I will end up with is a string which won't behave correctly when I sort by that date column.

Answer (score 0):

The third option I listed in my question was (partially) correct. I was using MM/dd/yyyy as format string but in moment.js the correct string is MM/DD/YYYY.

Once I registered the format I worked fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //register the date/time format(s) that you wish DataTables to detect and order 
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MM/DD/YYYY');
    ....
})
```

and then in renderer: (7th column is where my date is)

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": [6],
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            if (null == data)
                return data;
            return stringToDatestamp(data);
        }
    }
],
```

Javascript:

```
function stringToDatestamp(dateString) {
    var date = moment(dateString).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    return date;
}
```